# What is the preferred way to delete la arge amount of data from a Drupal site?

Tags: nodes, entities

We have a client site that currently has a very, very large data set in Drupal. We are working on generating a 'stripped' copy of the database to be used for testing new code by eliminating the bulk of the site content.

To this end, we need to periodically delete 40 million+ nodes and field collection entities from Drupal to strip down a copy of the production database so it can be used more readily on our staging and local development instances.

This is somewhat beyond what [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) or [Bulk Delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/bulkdelete) (Nodes) or other similar contrib solutions can handle in a reasonable time, not to mention that many of the field collections are not on node objects. I suspect that using node_delete_multiple() and entity_delete_multiple() for millions of items may be a non-starter time-wise, even if batched through either the queue API or the batch API.

Is there any way to 'cheat' by TRUNCATING the field_data_* and field_revision_* tables in MySQL to speed the record deletions?

Comment: For testing purposes, just investigate all tables that connected with Node. Then write script that truncate it.

Comment: I think this is a dup, but I handle stuff like this with one-off `drush scr` scripts instead of Batch API.  By not using the API you risk orphaned data in the database as the result of `hook_node_delete()` and `hook_entity_delete()` not running.

Comment: Using [this guide](http://timonweb.com/how-insert-and-update-only-specific-fields-your-entity-drupal-7) as a template and using [these functions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/7/search/field_sql_storage_field_storage_delet) I think you could get something working for mass deletes. Using [drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) (command line) or [httprl](https://www.drupal.org/project/httprl/) (custom code) you should be able to parallelize the job.

Comment: @MPD - Oh, I am more than aware that this isn't best practice. But to delete these all via node_delete_multiple() and entity_delete_multiple() is projecting to take somewhere around a week's time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any simple way to truncate (or truncate from X) a table like this.   The tables that would contain field data would be all mixed up and not nicely sorted.

In this case I would;

- Start with a view that generated a list of node IDs based on your
  select criteria (content type, status, older than date published,
  etc)
- Write a custom module with a drush command
- Load the node IDs
- Either [node_delete($nid)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete/7) OR...
- Examine what node_delete() does and `delete * from {table} where nid= $nid`

The tables node_delete() may touch will largely be dependant on your content types.  node_delete() will do the job, doing it my hand will take more time to prepare but may be faster to run. With the volume of records you're talking about a few milliseconds per delete may save a decent chunk of time.

Comment: We want to delete all nodes of type X and all field collections of type Y, and neither type has fields shared with content we don't want to delete. So in a sense, I know all the field tables for these fields can be truncated.

Comment: As above, using node_delete_multiple() and entity_delete_multiple() via batches or queues is projecting to take about a week to complete, which is far too slow at this point.